# Hosting web services on Mac OSX Snow Leopard

Tags: mysql, web-services, apache, macos

Does anyone what options exist for developing and hosting web services on a Mac OSX Snow Leopard server?

Is webobjects still supported, are there other solutions?
Does Python or PHP have a solution on Mac that also has libraries for working with MySQL?

Any help appreciated,
Thanks // :)

Answer (score 1):

Pretty much everything interesting (save MS .NET) runs on the Mac. Python, PHP, Java (Tomcat, Glassfish, JBoss).

Depending on the level of support you're looking for, any of those will likely fit the bill.

With Netbeans and Glassfish, you can have a SOAP webservice up and running in 10 minutes.